# vb.net The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a Data Grid View where when I click on the Viewdtails button in the grid, it then populates the Exception Details Grid right below it. That works fine, but I have a second query that is populating a history grid for the user to see but when I uncomment this out and run it I get the error "The method or operation is not implemented." And then my first query doesnt return an results at all. How can I rewrite this to run both queries and populate both grids?

```
   Protected Sub CountAlerts_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles CountAlerts.RowCommand
    If (e.CommandName = "Viewdtails") Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

        Dim abc, Unit, Cell, DTTM, prod, Query As String
        'Dim qry2 As String
        Dim DS As DataSet
        'Dim DS2 As DataSet

        abc = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("ABC")
        Cell = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("Cell")
        Unit = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("Unit")
        DTTM = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("CycTimeDate")
        prod = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("ProductDesc")

        For Each irow As GridViewRow In CountAlerts.Rows
            If irow.Attributes("class") = "highlight" Then
                irow.Attributes.Remove("class")
            End If
        Next

        CountAlerts.Rows(index).Attributes("class") = "highlight"
        Query = "EXEC [Audits].[dbo].[DetailsCombined] '" & abc & "', '" & Cell & "', '" & Unit & "', '" & DTTM & "', '" & User.Viewing & "' "
        DS = SelectQuery(Query)
        ExceptionDetails.DataSource = DS
        ExceptionDetails.DataBind()

        'qry2 = "EXEC [Audits].[dbo].[TrackerCombined] '" & abc & "', '" & Cell & "', '" & Unit & "', '" & StartDate.Text & "', '" & EndDate.Text & "', '" & User.Viewing & "' "
        'DS2 = SelectQuery(qry2)
        'ExceptionHist.DataSource = DS2
        'ExceptionHist.DataBind()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the full code? not yet implemented means what it says, your calling a method that doesn't have any code. Are you calling anything else before or after binding DS2?

Comment: Im just calling the first query with DS, nothing before that. And then I would like the second query to populate after the first. Im not calling anything after the second one. Its just those two when the "Viewdtails" button is clicked. When the second one is commented out, the first runs fine. Its just trying to incorporate the second query is where Im stuck.

Comment: Can you post the full error you get and what line it references?

Comment: Line: 939
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: what line of code is 939?

Comment: There is no line of code on 939, the class only goes to 140, but when I click the developers tool, it says this.        var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
        Sys.Observer.raiseEvent(this, "endRequest", eventArgs);
        if (error && !eventArgs.get_errorHandled()) {
            throw error;
        }
    },

Comment: That is what is on line 939.

Comment: Are you using AJAX/update panels? If you disable these do you still encounter this issue?

Comment: I did disable the update panels and it still failed. Im going to delete the pages, save the solution, do a system shutdown, reboot and recreate the page. I noticed that the designer was not updating for that one particular page when I would delete or add a control. Yet it worked for other pages, so Im thinking that page is corrupted somehow and lets start fresh. ??

Comment: Seems odd, wouldn't hurt to try, I reckon it's something to do with Ajax extensions as there isn't anything in the code you posted that would cause this as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well I went back to an earlier suggestion in which I move the gridview outside the update panel, and everything worked fine. Funny how the simple things tend to get you. Thanks for your help and suggestions. :-) Cheers!